# Facebook API hide/show page app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

My web site allow to users manage apps on their pages. I already implemented request to change tab name :

```
Uri url = new Uri(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{1}", pageId,tabId));

Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();

args["custom_name"] = tabName;
args["access_token"] = accessToken;

MakeRequest(url, HttpVerb.POST, args);
```

...
I have requests to add application to page and delete.

I can't find how to Show/Hide tab on page. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can do this via POST and DELETE requests to `/PAGE_ID/tabs` - you'll need the `manage_pages` permission for these calls, which are documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I have all permissions for request , but my question is what is request parameter for show/hide application on page. For example if i want to set page tab as Landing i need "is_non_connection_landing_tab" parameter to request. I just can't find this on developers.facebook.com

Comment: There is no actual “show/hide” via the API – just install or uninstall (delete); both are described in the linked document. And the “landing page” stuff is not relevant any more – there is no such thing any more on the timeline view for pages.

Comment: As CBRoe's comment says, landing tabs were for pre-timeline pages, and apps are either installed or not installed, there's no 'installed but not visible' option - just remove the app and put it back if you need the tab at a later time